# docker-compose detach keyboard shortcut?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running Docker Desktop 4.2.0 on Windows 10 Pro.

Until recently, to detach from containers after running docker-compose up, I could use the keyboard shortcut `CTRL + z`. This stopped working. How to fix it?

I know I can run docker-compose up -d and docker-compose logs -f but would prefer to use the original way. Other answers I found on stackoverflow suggest `CTRL + p, CTRL + q` or `CTRL + \` but neither works.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) says that the key sequence is "CTRL-p CTRL-q", a sequence of 2 keys.

Comment: @harrymc I had no luck with the sequence, does it work for you?

Comment: I don't have Docker here. Do you have the `detachKeys` property in your `~/.docker/config.json`? It should look like: `{` new-line `"detachKeys": "Ctrl-d,d"` new-line `}`. See [link](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14226/how-to-detach-from-a-docker-container-without-stopping-it/) for more info and another method using `kill`.

Comment: I don't think the "cont-p cont-q" sequence will work because you're not attached to "a" container with `docker-compose up`, you're watching the output of lots of containers. By not specifying the `-d` you're also implicitly saying you want to watch the output in real time and destroy the entire stack/project when you hit "cont-c", so I believe you're working around the design of the tool.

Comment: @harrymc tried your suggestion without any luck. I added "detachKeys": "Ctrl-d,d" to the config file in C:\Users\USERNAME\.docker\config.json but not working. Also tried "Ctrl-d" variant and still no luck. I would be curious to know if it actually works in your case.

Comment: I don't have Docker here. Does the `kill` method from [this link](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14226/how-to-detach-from-a-docker-container-without-stopping-it/) work for you?

Comment: @BMitch I actually could detach for about a year and then it stopped working some weeks ago. Once detached, I could either `docker-compose stop` or `docker-compose down` but there was no necessity to destroy the containers.

Comment: The described kill method does not destroy the containers, only their attached interface. See the section "Detaching When The Keyboard Sequence Won’t Work".

Comment: @harrymc there's no `docker.attach` process on Windows.

Comment: "cont-z" isn't to detach in docker, it's a shell command to suspend the process in the background. The key detail is you weren't attached to a container, instead compose was monitoring logs, so trying to detach is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @harrymc Checked the section "Detaching When The Keyboard Sequence Won’t Work", no success.

Comment: @BMitch so what does `docker-compose up --detach` mean?

Comment: It means to skip "viewing the logs and then stopping the project on `cont-c`". It's not the inverse as `docker attach` because it's not a single container. Your keystrokes are going to compose, not the containers you're monitoring. And so all the advice that tells how to detach from "a container" will not help here.

Comment: If there's no process on Windows that looks like being `docker.attach`, then you're not attached.

Comment: @harrymc yes, I understand now, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there will be a key sequence to detach from `docker-compose` (or `docker compose`). The `<ctrl>-p <ctrl>-q` sequence is intended for detaching from containers you are attached to with stdin (and may also require a tty connection). Since compose is starting multiple containers and then showing the logs of those containers when you don't use the `-d` option, you're not really attached to "a container".

The `<ctrl>-z` sequence is a shell command, e.g. in bash, that suspends the job and sends it to the background. You can view background jobs with the `jobs` command, and either leave them running in the background with `bg` or return to the foreground with `fg`. This isn't specific to docker or docker-compose.

My typical advice is if you don't want to remain attached, then use the `docker-compose up -d` option, and to view the logs use `docker-compose logs`. This is because in the foreground, `docker-compose` is trying to act like a foreground daemon that exits what it's doing when stopped, which includes all containers that it created.

Answer (score 0):

Actually played with this again today and found a way to achieve what I want:

```
start /B docker-compose up
```

which is the Windows command line equivalent of Linux

```sh
docker-compose up &
```

Comment: this is what `docker compose -d` does, except possibly with some other considerations.